# How can big Arduino programs be analyzed easily?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have an Arduino project code, but the problem is it has multiple functions and flow of control.

How could I convert this code into flowchart or control flow diagram?

Any software or online website?

Comment: Use doxygen and configure for full control and structure graphs.

Comment: Seems like you should be going the other way - create the flow chart first, then write the code to follow it.

Comment: Yes flow charts on function call level may be generated with doxygen (calls and callers). More details for instance here, https://romanegloo.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/generating-a-callgraph-by-using-doxygen-and-graphviz-13/

Comment: Another tool to quickly analyze code is Source Monitor. Allows a "statistic" approach to navigating the code. http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html

Comment: With respect, how is this a question about Arduino?  The same question could be asked about almost any large program in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are programs who can automatically make some documentation (like doxygen), I haven't seen any software so far that can make USEFUL flowcharts or diagrams. The main reason is that such software does not know which are the important parts and which are not.

To do it manually:

Assuming your code contains multiple files, use an UML (Unified Modeling Language) application. Than if classes are used, you can easily port them to UML, otherwise assume each (.c) file is a 'class'.

By adding properties/fields and methods (functions) and drawing dependencies between the classes/files you get a good idea how everything works together.

Comment: this is not what he asked. he wants an automatically created flow chart

Comment: @Juraj ... true I will update my answer.